# Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. -AS3

Tags: android, actionscript-3

i got this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at TriviaGameDeluxe/saveScore()[TriviaGameDeluxe::frame102:19]
```

This is my code:

```
//**//
playAgainbutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,saveScore);


function saveScore(event:MouseEvent) { // Save the score


if (savedSN == null) { // Check if a game save is created. If it is not, create one 
trace("New game save created");
savedSN = { // Set the varible 'savedSN'
            name1:"-",
            name2:"-",
            name3:"-",
            name4:"-",

        score1:"-",
        score2:"-",
        score3:"-",
        score4:"-"};
soSavedScNa.data.nameScore = savedSN; // Set the data in the save file to the 
savedSN variable
soSavedScNa.flush(); // Overwrite existing save file

}

    //**// Save the score
        if ((gameScore > savedSN.score1 || savedSN.score1 == "-") && 
gameScore != 0) {
            trace("Score 1");
            savedSN = { // Set the date the savedSN varible will have
                    name1:PName.text,
                    name2:savedSN.name1,
                    name3:savedSN.name2,
                    name4:savedSN.name3,
                score1:gameScore,
                score2:savedSN.score1,
                score3:savedSN.score2,
                score4:savedSN.score3};
            soSavedScNa.data.nameScore = savedSN; // Set the data in 
the save file to the savedSN variable
            soSavedScNa.flush(); // Overwrite existing save file
            playAgainbutton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, 
saveScore);
            cleanUp();
            gotoAndStop(1); // Go to the start menu
        } else if ((gameScore > savedSN.score2 || savedSN.score2 == "-") && 
gameScore != 0) {
            trace("Score 2");
            savedSN = { // Set the date the savedSN varible will have
                    name1:savedSN.name1,
                    name2:PName.text,
                    name3:savedSN.name2,
                    name4:savedSN.name3,
                score1:savedSN.score1,
                score2:gameScore,
                score3:savedSN.score2,
                score4:savedSN.score3};
            soSavedScNa.data.nameScore = savedSN; // Set the data in 
the save file to the savedSN variable
            soSavedScNa.flush(); // Overwrite existing save file
            playAgainbutton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, 
saveScore);
            cleanUp();
            gotoAndStop(1);
             // Go to the start menu
        } else if ((gameScore > savedSN.score3 || savedSN.score3 == "-") && 
gameScore != 0) {
            trace("Score 3");
            savedSN = { // Set the date the savedSN varible will have
                    name1:savedSN.name1,
                    name2:savedSN.name2,
                    name3:PName.text,
                    name4:savedSN.name3,
                score1:savedSN.score1,
                score2:savedSN.score2,
                score3:gameScore,
                score4:savedSN.score3};
            soSavedScNa.data.nameScore = savedSN; // Set the data in 
the save file to the savedSN variable
            soSavedScNa.flush(); // Overwrite existing save file
            playAgainbutton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, 
saveScore);

            cleanUp();
            gotoAndStop(1); // Go to the start menu
        } else if ((gameScore > savedSN.score4 || savedSN.score4 == "-") && 
gameScore != 0) {
            trace("Score 4");
            savedSN = { // Set the date the savedSN varible will have
                    name1:savedSN.name1,
                    name2:savedSN.name2,
                    name3:savedSN.name3,
                    name4:PName.text,
                score1:savedSN.score1,
                score2:savedSN.score2,
                score3:savedSN.score3,
                score4:gameScore};
            soSavedScNa.data.nameScore = savedSN; // Set the data in 
the save file to the savedSN variable
            soSavedScNa.flush(); // Overwrite existing save file
            playAgainbutton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, 
saveScore);
            cleanUp();
            gotoAndStop(1); // Go to the start menu
        }
    }
```

I cannot find where the error is.. Hope anybody can help. Thanks.

Comment: Show the line no: #1009

Comment: That's not the line number, that's the error number. We need to see line 19 on frame 102. Although this indicates that you've done your code on the timeline across multiple frames, which isn't usually best practice

Answer (score 0):

It is, indeed an error on line 19 of frame 102. This looks like it's the line that first refers to 'soSavedScNa' and, at that point, Flash has not heard of that variable before. It is a null object - hence the error. You need to declare it as a type of variable and define it before you can refer to any of the instance properties.

Comment: Thanks. I just declared the variables in the main class and it works!

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the object find out which object you have not properly declared.

Correct format

obj:object = new object()